# How to insert variables inside a string containing ""?

Tags: bash, shell, variable, xml

I want to construct an xml string by inserinting variables:

```
str1="Hello"
str2="world"

xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><tag1>$str1</tag1><tag2>$str2</tag2>'

echo $xml
```

The result should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><tag1>Hello</tag1><tag2>world</tag2>
```

But what I get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><tag1>$str1</tag1><tag2>$str2</tag2>
```

I also tried

```
xml="<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><tag1>$str1</tag1><tag2>$str2</tag2>"
```

But that removes the inner double quotes and gives:

```
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=iso-8859-1?><tag1>hello</tag1><tag2>world</tag2>
```

Comment: An XML document cannot have 2 top-level tags. Also, it's 2016, I would **strongly** recommend using utf-8, not iso-8859-1.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can embed variables only in double-quoted strings.

An easy and safe way to make this work is to break out of the single-quoted string like this:

```
xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><tag1>'"$str1"'</tag1><tag2>'"$str2"'</tag2>'
```

Notice that after breaking out of the single-quoted string, I enclosed the variables within double-quotes.
This is to make it safe to have special characters inside the variables.

Since you asked for another way, here's an inferior alternative using `printf`:

```
xml=$(printf '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><tag1>%s</tag1><tag2>%s</tag2>' "$str1" "$str2")
```

This is inferior because it uses a sub-shell to achieve the same effect, which is an unnecessary extra process.

As [@steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver) wrote in a comment, in modern versions of bash, you can write like this to avoid the sub-shell:

```
printf -v xml ' ... ' "$str1" "$str2"
```

Since `printf` is a shell builtin, this alternative is probably on part with my first suggestion at the top.

Answer (score 13):

Variable expansion doesn't happen in single quote strings.

You can use double quotes for your string, and escape the double quotes inside with `\`. Like this :

```
xml="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?><tag1>$str1</tag1><tag2>$str2</tag2>"
```

The result output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><tag1>hello</tag1><tag2>world</tag2>
```